# Chrome inconsistency when rendering Google Fonts

Tags: google-chrome, webfonts

These screenshots are both taken from the same source code:

[image]
[image]

You can probably guess it, these are rendered with the latest Google Chrome (43) on Linux.
As you can see, the result varies greatly, and I have no idea why.

The only thing I did was open the page in a new tab, and somehow I get on of those results randomly (usually one of the first 2 screenshots)

The relevant parts of the code, *i.e. everything that touches the font `-family`, `-style` or `-weight`*:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.timetable .organisation {
  font-style: italic;
}

.timetable .title {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

You can see it for yourself [there](https://eric.engestrom.ch/cv.html) *(the code is live, I don't care about that bug enough to make a dev copy)*

As far as I can tell, the first screenshot show the correct font rendering (where it's thinner), the other one being `sans-serif`, which is next in the `font-family` list.

Google Fonts seems to be serving the font in `WOFF2` format *(checked by opening [the imported CSS](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,600) directly in a tab)*.
I have no idea how to check the font format actually loaded in the page.

I have tried everything remotely related:

- [changing the order of the CSS and JS inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128549/239714)
- [adding an opacity animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22025804/239714) (even though [that bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c40) should be fixed)
- [adding some font-smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164981/239714)

This "related questions" are not related:

- [Chrome not respecting font weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249654/chrome-not-respecting-font-weight) → The `font-weight` does exist in this font.
- [Inconsistent font size rendering issue on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845183/inconsistent-font-size-rendering-issue-on-chrome) → The `font-size` is set in `px`.
- [Chrome is not displaying google fonts when all other browsers do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828509/chrome-is-not-displaying-google-fonts-when-all-other-browsers-do) → The `font-style` is correct.
- [Chrome not loading website when Google Fonts are installed/running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681220/chrome-not-loading-website-when-google-fonts-are-installed-running) → The page doesn't freeze.
- [Google I/O - Roboto Font (new version) font rendering issues in Chrome (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549096/google-i-o-roboto-font-new-version-font-rendering-issues-in-chrome-windows) → I'm not on Windows.
- [Google Chrome Font Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615109/google-chrome-font-rendering) → I'm not on Mac OS.
- [Chrome on Mac rendering font sizes inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858373/chrome-on-mac-rendering-font-sizes-inconsistently) → I don't have any accessibility settings set and my "minimum font size" is set to 10, i.e. much below the sizes used here.
- [Font family automatically changes to “undefined,sans-serif!important” in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016793/font-family-automatically-changes-to-undefined-sans-serifimportant-in-chrome) → disabling all the extensions changes nothing

It might be related to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273763/fonts-changing-weight-when-uploaded-to-web-server), although my experience differs, as the results change randomly here.

Comment: Somehow the problem seems to be with the `font-weight` of `400`; setting it to `300` fixed it. This is not a solution, but an acceptable fix. I still want to know what the actual problem is :)

Comment: Do you have a local version of Open Sans installed? Google Fonts refers to the local version first. Regarding checking what font is used: Right click on an element, then "Inspect", then go to the Computed Styles panel. At the bottom it shows you the used fonts. If you still see the random switching in font weight and variations in rendering, please file a bug at http://crbug.com